# How can I make an API request in python using the same credentials from Chrome?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am working with my company's RESTful API to query an internal server. My requests work fine when sent from the browser but I get blocked when working with python `requests` or with Postman. I am hoping to:

- Exactly replicate the original API request (with headers and authorization) that I executed with Chrome in my python script.
- If it is still blocked, diagnose the barrier to report to our IT head (who has never accessed the API through anything other than a browser and is reluctant to put time into the issue).

The input to Chrome is simply: `https://<company-address>/<endpoint>`

When I input this into python:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url=`https://<company-address>/<endpoint>`, verify=False, timeout=100)
    print(r.status_code)
    try:
        print(r.json())
    except:
        print(r.raise_for_status())
```

Yields the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etapro_swagger.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "etapro_swagger.py", line 37, in main
    print(r.raise_for_status())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://<company-address>/<endpoint>
```

---

I've tried putting my global credentials into the header with `headers={'username':'<user.name>', 'password': '<password>'` but still no luck.

In Chrome, I went to `Inspect -> Network -> Headers` to inspect the successful request but don't know how to verify what specific headers there should be input into python or how to do it.

Thanks and I'm happy to give more information as needed.

Comment: Your header is incorrectly formatted, is my first guess. Additionally, are you sure that the company endpoint needs a GET?

Comment: I think my formatting is not the issue because I've tried this through Postman as well which formats for you (and has worked with other APIs). 


No, I am not sure it needs a GET. How can I check? When I inspect the Chrome input, the Request Method is GET.

Comment: Well, in the past with Chrome, can you get the COOKIE in the header?

Comment: Yes, I see a few items under the Cookies tab: AES.NET_SessionId, _ga, _gid.

I added them as a `cookies` arg in `requests.get(cookies=)` but still same block.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is using a username/password combo you should be able to do the following:

```
import requests
Username = '<username>'
Password = '<password>'
r = requests.get(url=`https://<company-address>/<endpoint>`, auth=(Username, Password), verify=False, timeout=100)
    print(r.status_code)
    try:
        print(r.json())
    except:
        print(r.raise_for_status())
```

but generally storing them in plain text in a script is bad. so read https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/04/29/encryption-and-decryption-with-simple-crypt-using-python/ and see if it helps with how to at least encrpyt the password when used.  No matter what though, you should use an account that has the lowest level access possible to accomplish the goal.

Comment: yes I have input my username / password but still get blocked. 

(Thank you for the package recommendation I usually just import from an external file but that is slick)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by other posts, I looked at the response-header from chrome and the authentication method was `WWW-Negotiate` which is different from Basic Authentication and the issue is resolved.

Thanks for talking me through it!